# python ndarray what are return values

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, histogram, numpy-ndarray

I use a different library and I want to have a result like the output of this function. Is this a ndarray?
https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/stats.html#graph_tool.stats.vertex_hist

```
>>> a=gt.vertex_hist(g, "out")
>>> print(gt.vertex_hist(g, "out"))

[
  array([  5.,  32.,  85., 148., 152., 182., 160., 116.,  53.,  25.,  23.,  13.,   3.,   2.,   1.]),
  array([  0,     1,    2,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7,    8,    9,   10,   11,   12,   13,   14,   15],
  dtype=uint64)
]
```

The following function is from matplotlib.pyplot, returns counts and bins in two different vars:

```
    counts, bins, bars = plt.hist(list(nx.dict(degree(G)).values()),histtype='stepfilled')

    //output
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    [3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5]
```

How I can combine two list in one object/variable, or if I could understand which values the following expressions have:

```
for i in range(0,len(a[0])):
    v = a[1][i]
    c = a[0][i]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, `gt.vertex_hist(g, "out")` returns a `list` with 2 elements and each of these is an `ndarray`. the same is mentioned in the documentation.

Now the following expression, I am not sure of the purpose:

```
for i in range(0,len(a[0])):
    v = a[1][i]
    c = a[0][i]
```

Assuming that both the ndarrys will have same size always, this is simply iterating over the length of the first ndarray. It is assigning the current index value of the first ndarray i,e `[  5.,  32.,  85., 148., 152., 182., 160., 116.,  53.,  25.,  23.,  13.,   3.,   2.,   1.]` to `c` and current index value of the second ndarray to `v`. But everytime it is overwriting it, so `v` and `c` will only hold the last elements i.e 1 and 15 respectively. I think they should be appending it instead.

Comment: len(a[0]) isn't the length of the first array in ndarray? and a[0 or 1 means which array to get from the element] [which element to get] ?

Comment: yes, `len(a[0])` is the length of the first array in ndarray, but bothe the ndarrays have same length. So i ranges from [0, 15] here (both inclusive). The second part of your question is also correct